# Is it possible to transfer ownership of a Google Apps managed YouTube account?

Tags: youtube, google-workspace

I know it's not possible for normal Google accounts, but is it possible for Google Apps accounts?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to transfer the ownership from one account to another either for Google Apps accounts, but it's possible to transfer the account ownership to another user, even to change the username.